# Why does try catch not catch await function errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that if we have a try catch setup like this:

```
try{
   runSyncFunction()
}
catch(err){
  cosole.log(err)
}
```

If there is an error in the `runSyncFunction` the catch error will fire.

As per my understanding if we have try catch setup like this:

```
try{
   runAsyncFunction()
}
catch(err){
  cosole.log(err)
}
```

If there is an error in the `runAsyncFunction` the catch error will not fire because the function runs at a later time.

What I do not understand is why the catch error will not fire when we use await:

```
try{
   await runAsyncFunction()
}
catch(err){
  cosole.log(err)
}
```

If there is an error in the async function this time, and since the javascript engine is waiting for it to finish running why would it not be able to catch the error in case of an error.

**Edit1:**

```
router.post("/postDetails", async(req, res) => {
  try{
     let partID = await database.getPartID(partNumber[i])
     if (!partID) {
            throw createError(404, `"${partNumber[i]}" PartNumber not 
      found. Please re-enter the partnumber`)
    }
    //Other stuff  
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err) 
  }
})
```

Second function:

```
database.getPartID = async function getPartID(partNumber){
    try{
        let partID = await pool.query(`Select partID from parts where partNumber = '${partNumber}'`)
        return partID[0].partID
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return false
    }
}
```

I am returning false because the first async function does not throw an error message if there is an error in the second async function when there is a try catch block

Comment: The error should be caught in this case I believe... are you sure you’re using async await correctly?

Comment: I agree - Can you prove your point? Error should be caught if the awaited promise throws an error. If it catches the error itself and doesn't throw, so it resolves, you won't see the catch block getting invoked

Comment: Do you mind sharing the implementation of that function with us?

Comment: I have try and catch block inside the second async function. Is that the reason why the first catch would not fire?

Comment: provide the second async function.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Which exception is thrown in `getPartID` that does not get caught by the `catch`?

Comment: I recommend reading [Error handling with async/await and promises, n² ways to shoot yourself in the foot](https://catchjs.com/Docs/AsyncAwait).  I resolved a similar issue using _Promise Chains_ (using `.catch()` instead of `try/catch`).

Comment: If you don't await the async function it's error might be thrown after the `catch` part of the code has already been by passed, that's the simple reason why it won't catch without await - the code below your try/catch is already executing if you dont wait.

Answer (score 0):

These are some tips to use `try...catch`

> We can use `try...catch` for synchronous code.

> We can use `try...catch` (in combination with `async` functions) and the `.catch()` approaches to handle errors for asynchronous code.

> When returning a promise within a try block, make sure to `await` it if you want the `try...catch` block to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your second functions catch block is resolving the rejected promise. Therefore your first function is not catching the error. use `return Promise.reject(err)` in your second functions catch block, so that your first function can catch the error.